# What's the best way to geolocate a walkie talkie broadcasting on FRS channels using a UAV?

Tags: rf, uav

I'm researching methods to geolocate a fixed walkie talkie broadcasting on FRS channels. I need  to detect its location using a UAV. The UAV is fixed-wing, so it can not remain stationary. From what I've read so far, it seems like the best way to do this is probably to fly a pattern,  periodically take measurements of the signal strength and use trilateration to get a location to some accuracy. Can anyone give details on whether they think this is the best method, or if they would recommend a different method? What kind of location accuracy could I expect to have with that method? Are there any outside resources you could recommend related to this?

Thanks.

Comment: That sounds about right. Circle around based on signal strength

Comment: think in 3D ... the area of high signal strength will be smaller as you gain altitude

Comment: A walkie talkie will be intermittent transmission.

Comment: @jsotola - on the contrary, the opposite.  The higher the drone, the *larger*  the area!

Comment: @chris-stratton, the greater the distance, the weaker the signal due to inverse square law. So changing the height can help narrow down the origin.

Comment: @tim incorrect, the greater the height, the less signficiant horizontal distance (and horizontal **obstructions**) are, so the wider the area of reception at the strongest signal level.  Altitude is good for detecting it at all, but bad for localizing.

Comment: @chris-stratton, what if the origin of the signal is at a higher altitude than your current altitude?

Answer (score 2):

At ~460 MHz, a wavelength is less than 1 meter -- small enough to detect phase differences between multiple antennas at spacings that could be supported by a UAV.

From the phase differences between multiple antennas, you can calculate the direction to the source.  When you're far away, you could fly towards it.  When you get close enough to be mostly above the source, the direction vector will point to a spot on the ground, indicating the location.  Alternatively, if you fly around it enough to get significantly different directions, you can triangulate the location.  You'll have to get pretty close either way, since you can't expect the direction to be super accurate.

Comment: Typically this is done by electrically rotating an antenna, or more practically switching between several in a circular pattern, done right it imposes a frequency modulation from the doppler shift of the antenna "rotation" which demodulates nicely to an audio tone with a phase relative to the commutation.   But it's not usually done in 3D, likely you'd get your bearings while not *over* the target, but flying displaced paths *past* it.

Comment: I was expecting that these days you could arrange the antennas however you like, down-convert them all with the same quadrature LO, sample, and do the rest in SDR.

Comment: Matt, do you really need multiple antennas? If you know the UAV vector and can change it at will, the down-converted signal frequency from two UAV vector runs (perhaps at right-angles) gives you a solution. But it may take too much time if FRS is intermittent.

Comment: @glen_geek FRS walkie-talkies are FM-modulated, so the phase is not stable enough to compare across multiple runs, or even really at multiple positions along the same track at UAV speeds, I think.  I can't think of a way to do it with one antenna.

Comment: is a phased array one antenna?

Comment: @Jasen, no it is not